# List Indexing with Python

Tags: python, list

I was wondering why the following that when I have list in python , `lis`
Why does `lis[1:3]` only includes the 2nd and 3rd element of the list rather than 2nd, 3rd and 4th element?

Comment: Because the first index is 0, not 1.

Comment: When you have a slice such as `[a:b]` it starts at element `a` then goes to element `b-1`. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: because that's how slicing works...

Comment: @Wondercricket sorry that was a mistake

Comment: The problem is you have no natural way to represent an empty slice if `[a:b]` included `b`. `[0:0]` is an empty slice; if the end were included what would you do? `[0:-1]`?

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that it makes it easier to extract a sublist of a certain length.

For instance, `a[i:i+n]` will extract the sublist of length `n` starting at element `i` of the list `a`.

This convention also dovetails with the way `range(...)` and `xrange(...)` work.

Comment: ok, maybe I that makes it a little clearer why they use that convetion. I guess just first glance I would expect it to go other way